# Is there a way to break from a foreach loop in velocity?

Tags: velocity

I'm looking for a certain condition by using foreach to iterate through a collection (of permissions).  So if I find all that I need and don't need to loop anymore, is there a way to break out of the loop?  I am new to velocity and trying to grok this weird language.

```
#foreach ($perm in $space.getPermissions())  
#end
```

Comment: Velocity does not provide a #break, however there are ways to do the same thing:[http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/velocity-user/200310.mbox/%3C3F8541F2.70303@dlr.de%3E](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/velocity-user/200310.mbox/%3C3F8541F2.70303@dlr.de%3E)

Answer (score 62):

The latest version of Velocity (1.6) contains a statement #break

https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.6.2/user-guide.html#Loops

```
## list first 5 customers only
#foreach( $customer in $customerList )
    #if( $velocityCount > 5 )
        #break
    #end
    $customer.Name
#end
```